# Scala REHL jar importing issue

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I was trying to run a scala file using command
scala myclass.scala

However, it complains about one of the import library.  I included the jar using the -classpath option like this.
scala -class ncscala-time.jar myclass.scala

Error I got is:
myclass.scala:5: error: object github is not a member of package com
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using `-classpath` or `-class` because your command says you are `-class`

Comment: -classpath, a typpo, sorry

Comment: What happens if you set classpath to the current directory (i.e `.`) rather than naming the jar file explicitly?